# Delta Lake: don't we need time partition for full reprocessed tables anymore

Tags: apache-spark, architecture, etl, delta-lake, data-lake

### Objective

Suppose you're building Data Lake and Star Schema with help of ETL. Storage format is Delta Lake. One of the ETL responsibilities is to build Slowly Changing Dimension (SCD) tables (cummulative state). This means that every day for every SCD table ETL reads full table's state, applies updates and saves them back (full overwrite).

### Question

One of the questions we argued within my team: should we add time partition to SCD (full overwrite) tables? Means, should I save the latest (full) table state to `SOME_DIMENSION/` or to `SOME_DIMENSION/YEAR=2020/MONTH=12/DAY=04/`?

### Considerations

In one hand, Delta Lake has all required features: time-travel & ACID. When its overwritting the whole table, logical deletion happens, and you're still able to query old versions and rollback to them. So Delta Lake is almost managing time partition for you, the code get simpler.

In other hand, I said "almost" because IMHO time-travel & ACID don't cover 100% of use cases. It hasn't got a notion of arrival time. For example:

### Example (when you need time partition)

BA team reported that `SOME_FACT/YEAR=2019/MONTH=07/DAY=15` data are broken (facts must be stored with time partition any case, because data are processed by arrival time). In order to reproduce the issue on DEV/TEST environment you need 1 fact table raw inputs and 10 SCD tables.

With facts everything is simple, because you have raw inputs in Data Lake. But with incremental state (SCD tables) things get complex - *how to get the state of 10 SCD tables for the point in time when `SOME_FACT/YEAR=2019/MONTH=07/DAY=15` was processed? How to do this automatically?*

To complicate the things even more, your environment may come through bunch of bugfixes and history re-processings. Means 2019-07 data may be reprocessed somewhere in 2020. And Delta Lake allow you to rollback only based on processing or version number. So you actually don't know which version you should use.

In other hand, with date partitioning, you are always sure that `SOME_FACT/YEAR=2019/MONTH=07/DAY=15` was calculated over `SOME_DIMENSION/YEAR=2019/MONTH=07/DAY=15`.

Answer (score 1):

It depends, and I think it's a bit more complicated.

Some context first - Delta gives you time travel only limited to the current commit history, which is by default 30 days. If you are doing optimizations, that time might be significantly shorter (default 7 days).
Also, you actually can query Delta tables as of specific time, not only version, but due to above limitations (unless you are willing to pay the performance and financial cost of storing really long commit history), it's not useful from long-term perspective.

This is why a very common data lake architecture right now is medallion tables approach (Bronze->Silver->Gold). Ideally, I'd want to store the raw inputs in the 'bronze' layer, have a whole historical perspective in the silver layer (already clean, validated, best source of truth, but with whole history as needed), and consume the current version directly from "golden" tables.

This would avoid increasing the complexity of querying the SCDs due to additional partitions, while giving you the option to "go back" to silver layer if need arises. But it's always a tradeoff decision - in any case, don't rely on Delta for long-term versioning.

Comment: first of all, thans for your answer. Do you mean that "Silver" zone will have `SOME_DIMENSION/YEAR=2019/MONTH=07/DAY=15/<files>` partition approach, while "Gold" only the latest partition under `SOME_DIMENSION/<files>`? I think it only make sense when you have Lakehouse architecture and users self-service over Delta Lake tables. You'll still have all the complxity of querying SCD at "Silver" zone where all the ETL logic happens. The benefit is only for "Golden" zone (business) users. ETL won't read "Golden" at all. In my case I have "Golden" layer at Data Warehouse

Comment: also you can query Delta by time, but that is processing time. While tables are partitioned by arrival time: `SOME_DIMENSION/YEAR=2019/MONTH=07/DAY=15/<files>`. Because of re-processing this two times may not correlate

Comment: One moment, by partitioning, do you mean storing multiple Delta tables under different folders with time-based structure?

Comment: one delta table, but each partition will contain the full copy of data. One table makes metadata management easier.

Comment: Ok, so yes and no - I'd want the latest view in DW, whole history in "silver" zone, but not necessarily in full copy per partition format, as this might introduce problems later as system grows and processing is done more frequently. Ideally we could have all of the data versions in the table, but only if it actually changed between arrivals, and have partitioning that best supports most common queries (likely first by something like "isActive" switch).

Comment: sorry, this time I didn't understand your point. I still don't see how you're going to manage versioning by arrival

Comment: Long story short, I'd do change detection on each arrival and store only change "events", akin to event sourcing, while raw arrivals would all be stored in raw layer. But exactly how - this depends on the data and overall system requirements.

Comment: it's SCD, if to speak about ETL layer - you have to apply changes/merges on write, not on read. Actually you must have event sourcing (immutability) at raw layer (i.e. CDC for changes), but it's also very welcome on ETL layer